# How to listen for when a select box has an option appended to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box and I would like to know when another js function appends an option to it.  Are there any events triggered when this happens?

```
$('select').append('<option>Option 3</option>');
$('select').on('option_appended', function() {
    console.log('Option appended to select box');
});
```

Change doesn't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/CuQjV/

Comment: The only events that tell you when a DOM node is inserted are mutation observers, and they are pretty much deprecated, so the best option is to create your own custom events, and just trigger an event when the node is inserted.

Comment: You need to observe [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent). There is no jQuery function to handle this, other than an older, **deprecated**, `DOMNodeInserted`

Comment: mutationevents are deprecated but mutation observers are not. However support in various browsers is still unknown. Atleast mutation observers work with chrome/FF latest ones. But IE i am not sure.

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you Ohgodwhy

Comment: @nickromano DOMNodeInserted is deprecated try this http://jsfiddle.net/Rb2nN/

Comment: @nickromano keep this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver for your reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newest method is [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but support is not widespread, older deprecated method is [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) which are not hugely reliable and some [profoundly degrade the performance of the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Performance_best_practices_in_extensions). You could do this.

> Avoid DOM mutation event listeners
>
> Adding DOM mutation listeners to a document disables most DOM
>   modification optimizations and profoundly degrades the performance of
>   further DOM modifications to that document. Moreover, removing the
>   listeners does not reverse the damage. For the reason, the following
>   events should be avoided wherever possible: DOMAttrModified,
>   DOMAttributeNameChanged, DOMCharacterDataModified,
>   DOMElementNameChanged, DOMNodeInserted, DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument,
>   DOMNodeRemoved, DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument, DOMSubtreeModified

HTML

```
<select id="watch">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof window.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        window.MutationObserver = window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
    }

    var watch = document.getElementById("watch");

    function whenClicked() {
        var option = document.createElement("option");

        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Option" + Date.now()));
        watch.appendChild(option);
    }

    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", whenClicked, false);

    if (typeof window.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        watch.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (evt) {
            console.log("New element detected", evt.target);
        }, false);
    } else {
        var observer = new window.MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    console.log("New element detected", mutation.addedNodes[0]);
                }
            });
        });

        observer.observe(watch, {
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ga7C3/)

Note: I used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) in this example, which is also not cross-browser, search for `addevent` to find a cross-browser function. Or use the one on the given MDN page. I also used [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is an ECMA5 method, but there are shims, or you could rewrite using `for` or `while`.

Comment: Is this advice still valid? As of 2020 the `MutationObserver`is implemented in most browsers - even IE11. Just wondering if it should really be avoided or this only applies to the outdated `Mutation Events`. Any thoughts on that @Xotic750?

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger your custom event while adding option `.trigger('option_appended')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('option_appended', function() {
        console.log('changed');
    });

    $('select').append('<option>Option 3</option>').trigger('option_appended');
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/CuQjV/1/

Comment: My code isn't what is appending the option so I can't trigger it.  Thank you for your help though I should have been clearer with my question.